# Unable to output shape based off of user input

Tags: python

This program is supposed to print a rectangle of asterisks based on the number of `rows` and `asterisks` as specified from the user by the `input()` method. Included below is the non-working code that I am currently using:

```
numRows = input('Please enter the number of rows: ')
numRows = eval(numRows)

numAst  = input('Please enter the number of asterisks in a row: ')
numAst  = eval(numAst) 

for i in range(numRows):
    print(numAst*'*')
```

Comment: Is this homework? Python 3.x?

Comment: "It will not run" isn't enough information to know what is wrong.  Clearly describe the details of the problem.

Comment: This program does indeed output a rectangle of asterisks, so tell us what the output is and how it differs from the expected output.

Comment: Also, it's usually a very bad idea to `eval` user input. What if my input was `import os; os.system("rm -rf \")` or `import os; while 1: os.fork()`?!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are running the program under Python2

This will give you

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object
```

Try running with Python3

Note: Using `eval` like this is dangerous. Why not use `int` instead?

If you need a Python2 version. Replace `input` with `raw_input` and `eval` with `int`

```
numRows = raw_input('Please enter the number of rows: ')
numRows = int(numRows)
numAst  = raw_input('Please enter the number of asterisks in a row: ')
numAst  = int(numAst) 
for i in range(numRows):
    print(numAst*'*')
```

Comment: @JeffTratner, that is true for Python2. For Python3's `input` is the same as Python2's `raw_input`

Comment: @gosom, The only way I see it working with Python2 is to enter quotes around the numbers, so `input` will return a `str` object instead of an `int`

Comment: @gnibbler if you pass as input: '2' (as a string it works as it is)

Answer (score 0):

It runs in my machine , make sure you pass strings in the eval.
check here http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval